# How to get placeholder from string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with one or more placeholders in the following format: **$(*[name]*)**

The ***[name]*** can be any word (containing alfanumeric chars) and is case sensitive.

```
 Example1: 'The $(Quick) Brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
 Example2: '$(the) $(Quick) Brown fox jumps over $(the) lazy dog'
 Example3: '$(the) $(Quick) Brown $(fox) jumps over $(the) lazy $(dog)'
```

What is the best way in javascript to retrieve all place holders so that we have following result:

```
 Example1: ['Quick']
 Example2: ['the', 'Quick', 'the']
 Example3: ['the', 'Quick', 'fox', 'the', 'dog']
```

I also need to retrieve a unique list of placeholders, thus:

```
 Example1: ['Quick']
 Example2: ['the', 'Quick']
 Example3: ['the', 'Quick', 'fox', 'dog']
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard about regular expressions?

Comment: The [tag:placeholder] tag has totally different meaning.

Comment: P.S. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other answers have mentioned, your best approach is to use regular expression <strike>with the JavaScript `string.match()` function</strike>. My regular expression isn't the best it could be [*whose is*], but this should do the trick:

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/SdHMr/)

```
function getPlaceholders(str)
{
    var regex = /\$\((\w+)\)/g;
    var result = [];

    while (match = regex.exec(str))
    {
        result.push(match[1]);    
    }

    return result;
}
```

*Thanks [freakish](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/SdHMr/)*
​

Comment: Few modifications: use `regex = /\$\((\w+)\)/g` and `arr = []; while(match=regex.exec(example1)){ arr.push((match[1])); }` and we're there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with  [string's match function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 0):

Read this

#### http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/advanced-regular-expression-tips-and-techniques/

#### [http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html](http://swtch.com/%7Ersc/regexp/regexp1.html)

you can see more on [`Bookmark`](http://www.delicious.com/tag/regex)